# Laravel pass db data from controller to the view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I cant pass the db result to the view. If I debug it on Controller side everything is ok, so db query is working fine, but when I try to get the variable in view it says that variable is not defined.

Controller:

```
$records = DB::table('records')
        ->join('call_charges', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('records.inbound_originating_address_region', '=', 'call_charges.RateDestination')
                ->on('records.inbound_originating_address_type', '=', 'call_charges.RateType');
        })
        ->join('phone_types', 'records.inbound_originating_address_type', '=', 'phone_types.phone_type_id')
        ->orderBy('records.inbound_initiated_utc', 'asc')
        ->get();
return View::make( 'records.index' )->with( 'records', $records );
```

View:

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

    @if (Auth::check())

    <h2>Call records</h2>

        @if ( !$records->count() )
            No call records to view!
        @else
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Out call</th>
                    <th>Duration</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                    <th>Billable</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Caller</th>
                    <th>Receiver</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach( $records as $record )
                    <tr>
                    <td>{{ $record->inbound_initiated_utc }}</td>
                    @if ( $record->is_in_call == 1 )
                    <td class="success">Yes</td>
                    @else
                    <td class="warning">No</td>
                    @endif
                    <td>{{ $record->inbound_duration }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $record->session_total_charges }}</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>{{ $record->inbound_originating_address_region }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $record->inbound_originating_address_type }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $record->inbound_originating_address }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $record->inbound_destination_address }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        @endif

    @endif

    @unless (Auth::check())
        You are not signed in. Please sign in <a href='/auth/login'>here</a>
    @endunless
@endsection
```

Comment: Does it work with `->with(["records" => $records]);`?

Comment: Just tried, the same problem :(

Comment: Hmm Ok. Can you paste the whole error message? Specific line, etc. And also run a `dd($records)` right before your `return` statement and let me know what that says.

Comment: `FatalErrorException in 75d317ce14c300fc21f1325b6a642784 line 9:
Call to a member function count() on array` but if I remove count, it prints nothing, as variable does not exist

Comment: Ah, there's an issue. Should be `count($records)` since `->count()` can only be called on an Eloquent query and not an Eloquent collection. Also, if it prints nothing, it doesn't mean it's not defined, it means there's likely nothing in your result set. Run `dd($records)` before returning the view to see if there's anything **in** `$records`

Comment: `@if ( count($records) )
            No call records to view!
        @else` Now this statement executes and prints No call records to view, but there are lots of them if I var_dump the variable on the controller side.

Comment: `@if(count($records) == 0 ) No call records to view. @else` Check your logic ;)

Comment: Oh, my fault, sorry. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed the `return` statement to

```
return view("records.index")->with(["records" => $records]);
```

Next, using `->count()` can only be accomplished on an Eloquent query (before using `->get()` or `->first()`) to return a count of the results. After one of the closures, the logic needs to be changed to:

```
@if(count($records) == 0)
No call records to be view!
@else
...
@endif
```